How can I best store tomatos?
I buy tomatoes, and I keep them open inside the fridge.
If I don't eat them within a certain deadline, say, a week, tomatoes grow fungus.
How can I keep tomatoes fresh for longer?

tomatoes outside the fridge might grow fungus if they're so ripe they start leaking fluid... in the fridge might be a sign that you need to empty it and give it a good disinfecting

What is your indoor climate like? As in, temperature & humidity. A week seems awfully quick for potatoes

The original was two questions in one, which would have been closable. Since one of them is a duplicate (see Sneftel's link), I removed that part and only left the question about tomatoes. Also, I reworded it to be about optimal storage, because there is no reason to believe that they will last more than a week under optimal storage.

I can only cast one close vote, but https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/93324/how-can-i-save-tomatoes-for-at-least-20-days is a duplicate for the other half if someone else wants to do it.

@Sneftel thank you for finding that one! It's indeed a duplicate, I closed it.
